# AngularJS 1.3.0-beta.8 and greater breaks all my apps with $injector error

Tags: angularjs

So I was on version beta.6 and was working just fine...decided to go to the new version and immediately got some errors.  Started to work my way back and my apps work fine on beta.7 and then something happened between beta.7 and beta.8, which is not very clear but it is constantly throwing this error:

[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $filterProvider

Here is a sample of my angular app.

```
'use strict';

var Countries = angular.module('Countries',['ngRoute'])
.config([
    '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider
             .when('/Countries', { controller: TabsCtrl, templateUrl: '/Areas/MIS/Templates/Countries/tabs.html' })
             .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Countries' });
     }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to extend module 'ng'. Documented here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c0b4e2db9cbc8bc3164cedc4646145d3ab72536e

Covered by this error report: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7709 and this one: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9692

Comment: How am I extending it?  I am just injecting ngRoute into my app.  It used to be included in the angular.js then they broke it out into its own file, so then you have to inject it into your apps.